# Как создать список ListView в фрагменте?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-fragment, списки

Есть рабочее приложение, но я не смог реализовать ListView в фрагменте, пришлось запихнуть в Activity, но хочется все-таки, чтобы приложение имело нормальный вид. Хочется, чтобы в приложении было только главное активити, все остальное - фрагменты. Список содержит ImageView и TextView. Помогите пожалуйста. Выкладываю рабочий активити.

```
public class BarInvent extends Activity {

private ListView listView1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bar_invent);

    Inventar weather_data[] = new Inventar[]
            {
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv1, "Нож «для сомелье» со штопором и открывалкой для бутылок"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv2, "Разделочная доска, маленький ножик с коротким лезвием для резки фруктов"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv3, "Барная ложка для смешивания, чаще всего она используется обратной стороной для выливания слоистых коктейлей"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv4, "Бадья для хранения льда (ice bucket)"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv5, "Шейкер. Первый вариант - престижный и элегантный металлический шейкер, состоящий из трех частей - вазы, фильтра и крышки. Его недостатком является слишком большая теплоотдача, ускоряющая таянье льда и холодящая руки."),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv5_1, "Второй вариант - это «Бостон шейкер» из двух элементов -металлического и стеклянного. Он находит все большее и большее применение в Европе, что объясняется более медленным таянием льда в таком шейкере, и это позволяет дольше взбивать коктейль. Недостаток такого шейкера в его хрупкости"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv6, "Щипцы для льда"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv7, "Барное ситечко (стейнер)"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv8, "Бокал для смешивания, хотя вместо него можно использовать нижнюю часть шейкера"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv9, "Совок для льда"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv10, "Выжималка лимонного сока"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv11, "Воронка"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv12, "Термостойкий стеклянный кувшин"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv13, "Ведерко для шампанского"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv14, "Щипцы для открывания шампанского"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv15, "Дозаторы (джиггеры) - 2, 4, 6, 8 сантилитров"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv16, "Стоппер, пробка для закупоривания открытой бутылки шампанского"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv17, "Мельница для дробления льда"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv18, "Декантер (графин) для вина и порто"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv19, "Поднос (прорезиненный)"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv20, "Миксер (blender)"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv22, "Терка для мускатного ореха"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv23, "Барный органайзер (организатор)"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv24, "Риммер"),
                    new Inventar(R.drawable.inv25, "Мадлер"),
            };

    InventarAdapter adapter = new InventarAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_item_row, weather_data);

    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvBarInvent);

    View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    listView1.addHeaderView(header);

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Класс Inventar:

```
public class Inventar {
public int icon;
public String title;
public Inventar(){
    super();
}

public Inventar (int icon, String title) {
    super();
    this.icon = icon;
    this.title = title;
}
```

}

Адаптер:

```
public class InventarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Inventar> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
Inventar data[] = null;

public InventarAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Inventar[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    InventarHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new InventarHolder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (InventarHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Inventar inventar = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(inventar.title);
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(inventar.icon);

    return row;
}

static class InventarHolder
{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
}
```

}
bar_invent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvBarInvent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

listview_header_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    style="@style/TextStyleTitle"
    android:text="@string/bar_invent_title"
    android:background="#faac03" />
```

list_item_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    style="@style/TextStyle"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
```

Вызов из MainActivity (из NavigationDrawer)

```
 private void selectItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new AboutApp();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new NoBarmenNoParty();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new History();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Terminology();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new DesinityTable();
            break;
        case 5:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BarInvent.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
```

Comment: Нет никакой разницы где использовать ListView, какая была ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать ListFragment. Вот вам пример:
bar_invent.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MyListFragment.java:

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {
    TextView txtTitle;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bar_invent, container, false);
        txtTitle = new TextView(this.getActivity());

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<>();

        Inventar values[] = new Inventar[]{
                new Inventar(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha, "Some text")
        };


        ArrayAdapter<Inventar> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.textview, R.id.textview, values); //id вашего TextView R.id.textview
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Log.v("mUtem", item);

    }

    public class Inventar {
        public int icon;
        public String title;

        public Inventar() {
            super();
        }

        public Inventar(int icon, String title) {
            super();
            this.icon = icon;
            this.title = title;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот еще пару ссылок [ссылка1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) и [ссылка2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/ListFragment.java)

Comment: спасибо за ответ. не могли бы Вы продемонстрировать на моем примере? я смотрел все эти примеры, ну не понятно:)

Comment: @bodia7 внес правки, пробуйте. ListFragment использует свой адаптер,  если нужно кастомизировать, то адаптер нужно создавать самому.

Comment: или со мной что-то не так) или ошибка. Студии не нравится эта строка: new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.textview, R.id.category, values); конкретно textview, category

Comment: @bodia7 замените на R.id.textview

Comment: вот ,что выводит после запуска: пакет.BarInvent$Inventar@41bf79c8

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BarInvent extends ListFragment {
private List<ListViewItem> mItems;
     public BarInvent(){}// ListView items list

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
    Resources resources = getResources();

    mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.inv1), getString(R.string.first), getString(R.string.first_description)));
    mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.inv2), getString(R.string.second), getString(R.string.second_description)));
    mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.inv3), getString(R.string.fird), getString(R.string.fird_description)));

    setListAdapter(new ListViewDemoAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getListView().setDivider(null);
}


public class ListViewItem {
    public final Drawable icon;       
    public final String title;        
    public final String description; 

    public ListViewItem(Drawable icon, String title, String description) {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }
}

public class ListViewDemoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem> {

    public ListViewDemoAdapter(Context context, List<ListViewItem> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.bar_invent, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bar_invent, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            viewHolder.tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListViewItem item = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.icon);
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.title);
        viewHolder.tvDescription.setText(item.description);

        return convertView;
    }


    public  class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivIcon;
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvDescription;
    }
}
```

}